# Angular 9 new project - app-root not loading when ng serve

Tags: angular, angular-cli

i upgrade to Angular 9 and after making new project:
ng new test - when i'm doing: ng serve - the page not loading app-root.
when i add in the index.html some text - it's display the text but not the app-root.
i downgrade to angular 8 and same problem.
i have no error in the console.
i did ng build --prod and there is no errors.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test1</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
<p>test</p>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test1';
}
```

app.component.html

```
<p>Test inside app.component.html</p>
```

Comment: How about your main.ts file?

Comment: Are you sure about the correctness of your routing configuration (I see that you import AppRoutingModule)?

Comment: @TonyMarko
 ```import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: @S-Wing import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

Comment: When you do the "ng serve", does the console show any error? Is also the console of the browser clean/without errors?

Comment: That's the problem - I have no error in the console.. i have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: @Livnat Menashe did you find a solution?

Comment: @Kraulain Unfortunately no